# How would this SQL Server query look in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem trying to convert a query from SQL Server to MySQL so hopefully someone here help.

I was given the query below:

```
CREATE TABLE CustomerOrder (
    BusinessEntityID INT, 
    FirstName NVARCHAR(50), 
    MiddleName NVARCHAR(50), 
    LastName NVARCHAR(50), 
    EmailPromotion INT,
    OrderDetailsJSON NVARCHAR(MAX)
)

;WITH CTE_PersonContact AS (
    SELECT
        BusinessEntityID, FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, EmailPromotion,
        OrderDetailsJSON = 
        (   SELECT SalesOrderID, OrderDate, SubTotal, TaxAmt, TotalDue
            FROM [AdventureWorks2014].[Sales].[SalesOrderHeader] S
            WHERE S.CustomerID = P.BusinessEntityID
            FOR JSON AUTO
        )
    FROM [Person].[Person] P
)

INSERT INTO CustomerOrder
SELECT
    BusinessEntityID, FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, EmailPromotion, 
    OrderDetailsJSON
FROM CTE_PersonContact
WHERE OrderDetailsJSON IS NOT NULL
```

I'm currently stuck on how to convert the CTE part of the query especially the `OrderDetailsJSON` part, any help on how it's supposed to look like is appreciated

Comment: `.. SELECT BusinessEntityID, FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, EmailPromotion, (..) AS OrderDetailsJSON FROM ..`. The subquery must be rewritten according to MySQL syntax.

Comment: Rather than trying to convert code, frame your requirements completely with sample data and desired results.